# How to get httpstatus after click?

Tags: c#, .net, playwright

Using .Net and Playwright, I would like to validate/assert that once a Button/Link has been clicked.. the page loaded should return a statuscode within the 2xx-range. But I can't figure out how to capture the HttpStatus after a click. Basically this is what Im trying to achieve.

```
await Page.Locator(".mybtn").ClickAsync();
// Get the response.. anything like..
// Response.Status.Should().Be(200);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this? https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response

You can get the response and then verify whatever you need with it no?

Comment: Didnt notice that the 2nd argument could be a predicate.. perfect! Will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

**Verifying API response status on action:**

```
await page.RunAndWaitForResponseAsync(async () =>
{
    await page.GetByText("trigger response").ClickAsync();
}, response => response.Url == "https://example.com" && response.Status == 200);
```